# Auto Dial a phone number from web application on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, web, web-applications

I want to create a link on my html page for a phone number, such that clicking on that number will start a phone-call.

Using anchor tag with `href="tel:{phone number}"` we can create a phone-link, but in mobile browsers, clicking on such link will open the dialer-pad and show user to save to contact or make a call option.

I want to avoid all those things, instead clicking on number should auto-dial it and start a call (the way we have it on *WhatsApp* call)

Anyone has any suggestions here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You don't have control over how the device handles the `tel` links as this would open the gates for abuse of the device by malicious websites.

There are some apps, such as Facetime or Whatsapp, that do support opening the links and immediately take action, but they use customized URL schemes. When users click a link for Facetime or Whatsapp the first time they have to give allowance for the app to start.